# Can I prevent Git from compressing my audio files

Tags: git, github, audio, compression

The project I'm working on is stored in GitHub. It is a desktop app and has a few audio assets, that me and my team need to keep in the repository.

I quickly discovered that as soon as the files are pushed to the repository, they undergo a severe compression and become totally useless.

I cannot share the repository here, because it is private, but the audio files are simple sound effects in `.wav` format, that are no bigger than 2MB. We even decided to move to `.mp3`, in order to have smaller files. This worked fine, even though I'm not sure if git has done some further compression.

The problem is that we have only one bigger `.mp3`, about a minute long, that is a around 3MB. Of course, once pushed to the remote repository and pulled again, it has some cracks, due to compression.

I could not find any documentation about this. I don't know if it is a git-specific or a GitHub-specific problem.

Is there an option for me to configure the compression threshold? Or is there any other approach to solve this issue? I would argue that I'm not storing some insanely big binaries and it seems like a very common scenario.

Thank you for spending time on this!

Comment: Git compression does not corrupt files. What made you think that the audio files got damaged? Did you inspect the audio files? If the repository enables git-lfs, audios are most probably tracked as lfs files. If so, an audio file could be just a text file that has a link to the actual file. Before it's actually checked out, it can't work as an audio file. It happens when the client that has not installed and enabled git-lfs tries to clone a git-lfs-enabled repository. You could open the "damaged" audio with a text editor and see what's inside.

Comment: I realized the files are damaged after I commited them, then removed the branch, fetched it again and found that all the files are full of noise. I haven't opened them with texteditor, but when I pasted the original (not corrupted files) in the same directory, Git marked them as new changes - it means they are different files now.

Comment: Should all of our team members download and configure `git-lfs`, in order to resolve the issue?

Comment: good tut on this https://medium.com/junior-dev/how-to-use-git-lfs-large-file-storage-to-push-large-files-to-github-41c8db1e2d65

Comment: Or on GitHub zip the files and add them to a Release to keep them tied to the repo. You’d need to create some script when building which downloads and unzips assets in the right place. That should be achievable in a git hook

Comment: It's hard to believe Git would have corrupted the files, but there is one possibility: does Git think they are text files? If it's converting LF<->CRLF on you, that would corrupt the file. If that's the problem, you need to make sure Git knows they're binary files and then they won't get modified on check-in/check-out. Are the corrupted files almost the same size of the original ones? If my theory is right, you might see a 0.1% to 1% difference in size due to these line ending changes.

Comment: If my theory is correct, the only solution is to start from your good files again, making sure they are committed in as binary files. The files in your repo would not be fixable without a lot of work.

Comment: @joanis Maybe you're right, because this is what I get, when I commit the original files:
`warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in assets/audio/Theme_Song.mp3. The file will have its original line endings in your working directory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved, thanks to everyone that commented and shared insights. I will try to summarize the solution, based on all the comments and some of my findings:

1. Git compression does not corrupt the audio files in general.
2. I realised that something's wrong with the line endings of the files, because when I commit the original/unbroken audio files, I get this message:

```
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in assets/audio/Theme_Song.mp3. 
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
```

3. The `.gitattributes` file can provide configuration for the behaviour of line endings. It turned out that in my repository such file existed and it had a general rule, which I believe was the main culprit:

`* text eol=lf`

Since git treats the audio files as text, it is understandable why they go through this formatting. And this explains why they sound "broken" afterwards.

4. Adding `*.mp3 binary` to the `.gitattributes` file was enough to solve my issue. All `.mp3` files are now treated as binaries and don't go through formatting.